# Discord.py - How to track if someone joined from a specific invite?

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to figure out how to see who joined from a specific invite within my guild - is this possible? The end goal is for the bot to grant a role to a user if they joined from a specific invite, and grant a seperate role if they joined from a different invite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, but you'll have to do the heavy lifting.

[Here's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#invite) the reference for the `Invite` object. It has a `uses` attribute which stores the amount of times it's been used to join your server: so if you store all the possible invites for your server in memory, and check which one went up whenever a user joins (in `on_member_join()`, you'll be able to tell which one they used.

[This medium article shows a way to do it](https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f). There's no other way I'm aware of, or that I can find in the documentation.